# g++ error: ‘malloc’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, g++, malloc

I'm using g++ under Fedora to compile an openGL project, which has the line:

```
textureImage = (GLubyte**)malloc(sizeof(GLubyte*)*RESOURCE_LENGTH);
```

When compiling, g++ error says:

```
error: ‘malloc’ was not declared in this scope
```

Adding `#include <cstdlib>` doesn't fix the error.

My g++ version is: `g++ (GCC) 4.4.5 20101112 (Red Hat 4.4.5-2)`

Comment: Are you using namespaces? Is you malloc code in a namespace?

Comment: Are you sure the project should be compiled with g++?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You should use `new` in C++ code rather than `malloc` so it becomes `new GLubyte*[RESOURCE_LENGTH]` instead. When you `#include <cstdlib>` it will load `malloc` into namespace `std`, so refer to `std::malloc` (or `#include <stdlib.h>` instead).

Comment: If you *do* need to use a `malloc`-like function, in C++, consider using the function `operator new`, which interfaces with the rest of the memory system (it throws exceptions, calls the new handler if memory can't be found, etc.)

Comment: Since using `#include <stdlib.h>` dumps all declared names in the global namespace, the preference should be to use `#include <cstdlib>`, unless you need compatibility with C.

Comment: As I understand it, `#include <cstdlib>` will import `malloc` and friends into the `std` namespace, and may or may not import them into the global namespace, while `#include <stdlib.h>` will import them into the global namespace, and may or may not import them into the `std` namespace.

Answer (score 19):

You need an additional include. Add `<stdlib.h>` to your list of includes.

Answer (score 6):

### Reproduce this error in g++ on Fedora:

How to reproduce this error as simply as possible:

**Put this code in main.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int *foo;
    foo = (int *) std::malloc(sizeof(int));
    *foo = 50;
    printf("%d", *foo);
}
```

**Compile it, it returns a compile time error:**

```
el@apollo:~$ g++ -o s main.c
main.c: In function ‘int main()’:
main.c:5:37: error: ‘malloc’ was not declared in this scope
     foo = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
                                     ^
```

**Fix it like this:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
int main(){
    int *foo;
    foo = (int *) std::malloc(sizeof(int));
    *foo = 50;
    printf("%d", *foo);
    free(foo);
}
```

**Then it compiles and runs correctly:**

```
el@apollo:~$ g++ -o s main.c

el@apollo:~$ ./s
50
```

Comment: error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'char**' [-fpermissive]
     result = std::malloc(sizeof(char*) * count);

Comment: The error you are posting is unrelated to the malloc issue addressed in my post.  If you have a new question please use the "Add Question" button in the upper right.

Comment: malloc always returns void.  Please refrain from posting followup questions on answers that have nothing to do with your problem.